# Converting Java String to List of maps

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, maps

Having a String as below:

```
String s = "[{key1=value1, key2=4}, {key1=value2, key2=5}, {key1=value3, key2=10}]";
```

How can I convert it to `List<Map<String,String>>` in a gracious way?
Was thinking of using ObjectInputStream somehow, but not able to come up with something.

The problem here is String it is not exactly in standard json format.

Comment: So in essence you ask how to convert a JSON into a Java object? Use some JSON library like Jackson or GSON

Comment: @Turing85 this is not in the standard json format .

Comment: @dhruvsharma Where is it coming from?  Can you make the source include quotes so that it is standard JSON?  That'd be much easier than writing your own parser.

Comment: @azurefrog  no i cant do it .